# Ошибка с SSL сертифкатами в Angular приложении

Tags: javascript, http, angular, ssl

Лоакльно работает Angular приложение c https запросами. Вот PROXY_CONF файл

```
 const PROXY_CONFIG = [{
    context: [
        "/production/items"
    ],
    target: "http://resourse.1.com",
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false,
}];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Вот environment.prod.ts

```
 export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api: 'https://resourse.1.com/production/item-backend/v1',
  auth: 'https://resourse.1.com/production/item-backend/v1',
};
```

После деплоя на боевой сервис возникает ошибки при запросе на бекенд: `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`
Что может быть не так ?

Comment: попробуй поиграться с secure .. ну и changeorigin, в довесок ) вдруг "чО" )

Comment: `target: "http://resourse.1.com",` должен быть по http? (это вопрос)

Comment: @Greg-- пробовал и так тоже , не помогает. Я не мастер в Ангуляре , но PROXY_CONF вроде срабатывает на Localhost только и там заменяет